# Run a controller after another controller renders

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a `<div>` containing several sub-controllers, each of which generates a Highchart from inside the controller and a table from `ng-repeat` in the HTML file. I have a main controller which intends to take these HTML after they are fully generated, and append them into a different `<div>`. The `<div>` which contains generated HTML from the sub controllers will not be displayed. The `<div>` which contains the appended copy passed from the main controller is the one that will be displayed. However, the appended HTML contains only what is generated within the sub-controllers (Highcharts), but not what is generated in the ng directives in the HTML file (table rows). How can I resolve this?

Simplified version:

```
<div ng-controller="main">
  <div id="appendAndDisplay"></div>
  <div id="doNotDisplay">
    <div ng-controller="sub1">
      <div id="highchartHere"></div>
      <table>
        /* multiple <th> */
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="entity in entities">
            /* multiple <td> containing entity data defined in sub1 controller */
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What happens here is that the highchart and table is fully generated and viewable in `doNotDisplay`, but whatever the `main` controller copied out to append into `appendAndDisplay` contained only the highchart and the table headers, not the rows to be generated by angularJS - I'm guessing this is because highcharts doesn't use angularJS at all and is purely jquery.